# Was Joker Robin in Suicide Squad?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

I have watched and heard some rumours on Joker of [*Suicide Squad* (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/) about him being Robin. Was Joker really Robin? Because Joker was not that guy we know.

Comment: Huh? What does Joker have to do with Robin? Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Catija It's a famous fan fiction/rumor that this Joker is Robin and Robin was secodn Joker in animated film [Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond:_Return_of_the_Joker) too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rumor/fan-fiction was

> Second Robin Jason Todd was not killed by the psychotic villain after
>   all but instead turned into him. Fans have cited ‘evidence’ in
>   marketing material released during the run-up to Suicide Squad’s,
>   claiming that The Joker’s bullet hole tattoos match up with puncture
>   marks on the graffitied Robin costume seen hanging in the Batcave in
>   Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice.[*](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/suicide-squad-david-ayer-debunks-major-fan-theory-that-the-joker-is-robin-a7156691.html)

[image]

But that rumor was just fan fiction, nothing more then that and even David Ayer debunks it in a interview:

> Recently, Ayer was asked in a red carpet interview by WSVN-TV reporter
>   Chris Van Vliet to name the most ridiculous rumour he had heard about
>   the film. “That the Joker is Jason Todd,” he said. “It ain’t the case.
>   He’s not.” [www.independent.co.uk/](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/suicide-squad-david-ayer-debunks-major-fan-theory-that-the-joker-is-robin-a7156691.html)

Even Zack Snyder debunked it by mentioning there is a dead robin in DCEU:

> "In my mind, it was that Robin had died 10 years earlier, during some run in with a young Joker," he stated. "To me, it was a fun backstory… to play with. The whole idea was that there had been loss and sacrifice. [Batman] doesn’t really have a life outside of the cave. I thought by including Robin – a dead Robin – it would help us understand he’s been on quite a little journey."

Zack Snyder's interview was not that clear. But there was a self proof in Suicide Squad film itself with the intro of Harley Quinn:

[image]

Borrowed idea of image from KutuluMike's answer form related question, reading it might clear it more:

[What is the meaning of the graffiti saying “Joke's on You Batman”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/59595/1190)

Answer (score 10):

No, Joker was not a former Robin. Rather, Joker was responsible for *murdering* the former Robin, which we saw hints of in *Dawn of Justice* and then got confirmed in *Suicide Squad*. (Harley Quinn was arrested as Joker's accomplice to that murder.)

The characterization of Joker in that movie is different from most of the others we have seen on-screen, but Joker's character has varied quite a lot in the comics over the decades. This version of the Joker is much more low-key than others (almost polar opposite of the campy 60's Batman), and is playing more of a mob boss than a crazy terrorist, but he's still definitely playing the Joker.